# My reputation gain doesn't tally with the number of votes I get

Tags: support, up-votes, serial-voting, reputation-history

I'm seeing +65 reputation in [my reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430492/vusan?tab=reputation) (on July 8 / 2 days ago), but I'm getting only 12 up-votes for that post. I'm confused about why that happened.

Comment: I can see 13 votes. 13*5=65

Comment: do you see 13 votes on question?

Comment: yep. If you observe anything different, please post a screenshot.

Comment: up to now I see 12 votes on both: question and on my view profile

Comment: Weird, I also only see +12 votes, not +13.  Maybe it has something to do with the serial upvoting that was reversed.

Comment: I can see +65 from 13 upvotes and -300 from a serial upvote reversal on that day, -6 yesterday, -2 (so far) today. Caching issue?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes I see alt text as "this question was upvotes 13 times" but in question and in my profile it is showing 12 votes.

Comment: yep. +13 in the rep history, but only 12 left after the reversal

Comment: wow, -300 that's rather a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the upvotes on your question was reversed with the serial voting. Thus, you'd only have 12 votes left on your question. Your history would still show 13 votes that gained you reputation, because the -5 from the reversal would be included in the -300.